# How to prevent a popup from a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I have a hyperlink that when clicked will render a popup form.
However before the popup renders I want to validate some data first.
So in this case, if the client name already exists, do not render the popup to create a new client with that name.
So on my webpage I have;

```
<span id="buttonCreate" style="display: none;" class="bootstrapLink" 
                  data-itoc-check-name="@Url.Action("CheckClientName", "DataService")">Click "Create" if you want to use this name 
                <a href="#edit-client-popup" class="btn btn-info btn-xs create-client" data-toggle="modal">Create</a>
            </span>
```

and in my javascript I have the following code;

```
var popupUrl;
$('.create-client').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popupUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    var button = $('#buttonCreate');
    var clientName = getValue('clientName');
    var url = button.data('itoc-check-name');
    dataService.checkClientName(clientName, validateClientName, url);
});

var validateClientName = function (isInvalid) {
    if (isInvalid) {
        $("#errorMessageClientName").show();
        return false;
    }

    resetModalPopup();
    $("#editClientName").val(clientName);
    document.location.href = popupUrl;
    return true;
}
```

I was hoping that event.preventDefault(); would prevent the popup from rendering. If the validation passes, then document.location.href = popupUrl;
would render the popup, otherwise if the validation fails the error message - $("#errorMessageClientName").show(); - is displayed instead.
However event.preventDefault(); does not work, the popup is rendered.
It should be noted that validateClientName is a callback function, and that might be part of the problem. Setting the event in a global variable and attempting event.stopPropagation() in the callback function does not work.
The data-toggle="modal" attribute in the hyperlink is a bootstrap feature that renders a modal popup when the hyperlink is clicked.

So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is not 100% ideal, but I am happy with it.
Instead of trying to prevent the popup event from happening, just close the form instead.
So the callback function looks like this;

```
var validateClientName = function (isInvalid) {
    if (isInvalid) {
        $("#errorMessageClientName").show();
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    } else {
        $("#errorMessageClientName").hide();
    }
}
```

$('.modal').modal('hide'); is the line that hides the popup. So if the client name already exists and the validation fails, the form will render for a split second and close again. Not ideal, so if anyone has a better answer I will tick that. In the meantime since this error will hardly ever happen, this solution will do.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a pop-up scenario, and the user will have no reason to want to right-click the link to open a new tab, then remove the `<a>` tag altogether. Instead,

1. Wrap it in a `<span>`
2. Apply any desired styling to make it appear as a link should
3. Store the URL in a data attribute of some kind, and
4. emulate the link action by binding the desired function to a
   click-event.

Then you won't have to prevent anything. Another suggestion would be to include `event.stopPropagation()` as well as `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: event.stopPropagation()  stopped the popup from rendering, but then the document.location.href = popupUrl; did not work.

Comment: I followed your other steps, replacing the hyperlink with a span. The problem now is that document.location.href = popupUrl does not work, although the same url did render a popup previously.

Comment: To clarify further, the data-toggle="modal" attribute is a bootstrap feature that renders a popup only from a hyperlink.